# Submit application to spark EC2 (AWS EMR) cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm newbie in Spark. I have one simple query about using worker nodes. 
I have simple spark program - for example "WordCount" from Spark examples. I create EMR cluster with driver node and 2 workers. Connect to driver by ssh and submit task to Spark:

```
spark-submit --class mytest.application --master local[*] --deploy-mode client mytest.jar
```

Comment: Sorry, this post is not completed!

Comment: EMR is already set up for Spark on YARN, no need to specify master.